# Count number of missing value with Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, transformation, missing-data

I'm new to Pentaho and I'm trying to do a really simple task (I suppose), but I didn't succeed it. I have a CSV file which contains multiple column and row. I want to count the number of missing values in each row for each row. I tried to do so:
[image: From left to right "Extract from CSV" "group by" "Result in an excel file]

I try to used a "group by" box but I don't really know if it's appropriate.
Could you give me some hint or the appropriate box for my problem
[image: Input line]
[image: Expected result (Example)]

The first picture is a sample of some line from the file (which contain 69 column and 2 500 000 rows) and the second picture is the expect result (the number of null value per row)

Comment: Can you post some lines of the CSV with expected output?

Comment: I add picture of the input file and of the expected result is it enough?

Comment: I'm still unsure of how the number is 1 for the first line. What is it counting in that example? It's the number of columns with `0` as the value?

Comment: It's an example it's suppose to count the number of blank cell "" where there is nothing in it

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you have 4 missing values only in the screen for the first line of data, but in the example output you say 1.

Comment: This is an example there is 2 500 000 row it's may be not the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably some other way to do this, but it is possible to do this with a `Modified Java Script` step. Something like this will count the number of `null`'s.

```
var fields = getInputRowMeta().getFieldNames();

var nulls = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (row[i] == null) {
        nulls += 1;
    }
}
```

And then output the `nulls` value to the row from the step.

Comment: I try to launch the script I've got "ReferenceError: "getInputRowMeta" is not defined." as an error. Should I insert something like a library?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Pentaho Data Integration  - Spoon version General Availability Release - 5.4.0.1-130

Comment: Can you test if this transformation works for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xep8zy05wymim62/count_nulls.ktr?dl=0

Comment: Yeah it works, I don't see the difference with what I did anyway it's work now. So now I just have to add a line

Comment: I've got another question, is there any method which allow me to do it column by column? like instead of getInputRowMeta() getInputColumnMeta()

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Why do you need it column by column? You should be able to achieve this easily with `getInputRowMeta()`.

Comment: Because I'm trying to count the number of null per variables and not per observations. And I feel like the script is called at each row which make it hard to count the number of "null"

Comment: You want to count the number of nulls for a column? And then make a row that sums the numbers of nulls per column? It doesn't look like that in your question.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I want to do, this is why i'm looking for a method like: getInputColumnMeta() because with such a method like that it will be super easy. Sorry my english is not that good, still confused sometimes.

Comment: If you ask a new question I will try to answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368635/count-the-number-of-null-value-per-column-with-pentaho